JavaScript how to pass variable to second if statement
I have the below code which is an event listener for a chatbot.
The userType value is not being preserved or passed from the first if statement to the second if statement, the value is undefined.
How can I prevent the userType value from being cleared by the second if statement?
q('handleEvents', function(name, data) {
  var userType;
  if (name === 'QCP') {
    userType = "CP";
    console.log(userType);
  }
  if (name === 'EC') {
    console.log('EC found');
    console.log(userType);
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'qlc',
      'qUserType': userType
    });
  }
});


What value are you expecting it to have? The only code you've shown that sets it is userType = "CP";, but that can only execute if name is 'QCP'

There's no scenario in which both of those if statements would execute, their conditions are mutually exclusive.  Do you mean that you want the userType value to persist across multiple calls to this function?  If so then you'd need to use a scope outside of the function itself...

@NicholasTower userType = CP within the second if statement.

Ok, so do you always want usertype to be "CP"? if so, do var userType = 'CP', and probably delete the first if statement since it no longer changes the value

This question makes little sense. How can the variable persist from one if to the other if only one of them ever runs?

If name === 'QCP',  userType becomes "CP" else userType remains undefined.

Both if statements run. I need to link them together somehow,

Both if statements run? Impossible!

@ianhman: "Both if statements run." - Not in the same call to this function they don't.  If you think they do then you are observing multiple calls to this function and making false assumptions.

It seems that you don't understand that local variables are all reset each time the function runs. If you need the value to persist, it should be a global variable.

You could put userType outside the function. You could also seal it in a block so it could be visible to the event handler only (like a static function variable), avoid using var in the modern JS, learn about let and const. That way the variable will be preserved between the event listener's calls.
Also use else if to avoid the second check if the first is true:
{
   let userType;
   q('handleEvents', function(name, data) {
    if (name === 'QCP') {
      userType = "CP";
          console.log(userType);
    } else if (name === 'EC') {
          console.log('EC found');
      console.log(userType);
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.dataLayer.push({ 
               'event': 'qlc',
               'qUserType' : userType
         });      
    }
  });
}


The OP is not reproducible. ”Both if statements run. I need to link them together somehow” —Asker.

@ChukwujiobiCanon ‍♂️

My point is that we should stop answering such questions.
